# Duvida com Jquery

Tags: jquery

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho a imagem em anexo quando clico no checkbox, eu consigo dar o highlight nessa linha via o seguinte codigo :

```
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight_row");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("highlight_row");

    }
});
```

Pórem estou tendando fazer que quando eu clicar dois campos inputs que tenho no final ganhem a propriedade REQUIRED.
Deve ser algo simples porem estou patinando nisso.
Essa eh uma linha de onde posso ter 'n' linhas.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e inclua o html da tabela com os inputs

Comment: você pode dar um find no elemento já que tem o `$(this)`, ficaria mais ou menos assim: `$(this).parent().find().('.classe_do_input').attr('required', true);` com o `parent` você vai subir para o nível da linha e após isso procurar o elemento com a classe que você precisa.

Comment: @arllondias Penso que usar o `attr` não irá dar, usar o `.prop("disabled", true)` pode resultar em alternativa

Answer (score 0):

Levando em consideração que o `$(this).closest('tr')` é a `<tr />`. é só usar o `.find()` para achar os inputs do tipo *text*.
Exemplo:

para adicionar o *required*:

- `$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').attr('required', 'required');`

ou para remover o *required*:

- `$(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').removeAttr('required');`